# Read PR Title of a project on github

Tags: github

Is it possible to read the PR Title of a github repo?

I want to do some analysis over the data, currently I go and manually check the title and sometimes PR are very large in number

Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests). For example,
to get the pull request URLs and their titles in JSON format of `someuser`  in `somerepo`, using `curl` and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you could do:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/someuser/somerepo/pulls | jq '[.[] | { url: .url, title: .title }]'
```

The output will look something like:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/pulls/159",
    "title": "Remove the locally copied Alm.Authentication classes and use the NuGe…"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/pulls/108",
    "title": "New settings for Nuget package installation"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @janos will try to implement it.